# Unable to resume activity SuperNotCalledException. Activity did not call through to super.onResume()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working on an existing code base. I am trying to ad a deeplink to an *Activity*. However when I test the deeplink it goes to the *Activity* then the *Fragment* is loaded but then force closes with the following error. When I debug it goes up to the point where the rest call is enqueued but before the response the *Activity* closes.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
> {com.detail.Activity}: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
> {com.detail.Activity} did not call through to super.onResume()

However, I do have the override `onResume` method where `super.onResume()` is being called in both the *Activity* and the *Fragment* that it loads.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    try {
        if (settingsMain.getAnalyticsShow() && !settingsMain.getAnalyticsId().equals(""))
             AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().trackScreenView("Rating");
        super.onResume();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So not sure what is causing it and I am new to *Android* development. Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't called because `AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().trackScreenView("Rating")` throws an exception and the code jumps to the `catch` block resulting in the `SuperNotCalledException`.

It should be

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try {
        if (settingsMain.getAnalyticsShow() && !settingsMain.getAnalyticsId().equals(""))
            AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().trackScreenView("Rating");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```